# What's a functional replacement for if-then statements?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I've been learning F# and functional programming and trying to do things the functional way. However, when it comes to rewriting some code I'd already written in C# I get stuck at simple if-then statements (ones that only do something, not return a value). I know you can pull this off in F#:

```
if expr then do ()
```

However, I thought this was an imperative approach to coding? Maybe I've not learned enough about functional programming, but it doesn't seem functional to me. I thought the functional approach was to compose functions and expressions, not simply execute statements one after the other which is what if-then seems to encourage.

So, am I missing something and if-then is perfectly fine in the functional world? If not, what is the functional equivalent of such a statement? How could I take an if-then and turn it functional?

Edit: I might've asked the wrong question (sorry, still fairly new to functional programming): Let's take a real world example that made me even ask this:

```
if not <| System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) then do
    let byteData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)
    req.ContentLength <- int64 byteData.Length
    let postStream : System.IO.Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postStream.Flush()
    postStream.Dispose()
```

The body of that if-then doesn't return anything, but I don't know how I could make this more functional (if that's even possible). I don't know the proper technique for minimizing imperative code. Given F#'s nature it's fairly easy to just transport my C# directly, but I'm having difficulties turning it functional. Every time I reach such an if statement in C#, and I'm trying to transport it to F#, I get discouraged that I can't think of a way to make the code more functional.

Comment: The code in your edit is imperative by nature, you're chaining several actions together, not computing a value. F# can't help you make this more functional, but it does provide tools for isolating side effects and making them more noticeable.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An important point that hasn't been mentioned so far is the difference between `if .. then .. else` and `if .. then` without the `else` branch.

#### `If` in functional languages

The functional interpretation of `if` is that it is an expression that evaluates to some value. To evaluate the value of `if c then e1 else e2` you evaluate the condition `c` and then evaluate either `e1` or `e2`, depending on the condition. This gives you the result of the `if .. then .. else`.

If you have just `if c then e`, then you don't know what the result of the evaluation should be if `c` is `false`, because there is no `else` branch! The following clearly does not make sense:

```
let num = if input > 0 then 10
```

In F#, expressions that have side-effects like `printf "hi"` return a special value of type `unit`. The type has only a single value (written as `()`) and so you can write `if` which does an effect in just a single case:

```
let u = if input > 0 then printf "hi" else ()
```

This always evaluates to `unit`, but in the `true` branch, it also performs the side-effect. In the `false` branch, it just returns a `unit` value. In F#, you don't have to write the `else ()` bit by hand, but conceptually, it is still there. You can write:

```
let u = if input > 0 then printfn "hi"
```

#### Regarding your additional example

The code looks perfectly fine to me. When you have to deal with API that is imperative (like lots of the .NET libraries), then the best option is to use the imperative features like `if` with a `unit`-returning branch.

You can use various tweaks, like represent your data using `option<string>` (instead of just `string` with `null` or empty string). That way, you can use `None` to represent missing data and anything else would be valid input. Then you can use some higher-order functions for working with options, such as `Option.iter`, which calls a given function if there is a value:

```
maybeData |> Option.iter (fun data ->
    let byteData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)  
    req.ContentLength <- int64 byteData.Length  
    use postStream = req.GetRequestStream()  
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length) )
```

This is not really less imperative, but it is more declarative, because you don't have to write the `if` yourself. BTW: I also recommend using `use` if you want to `Dispose` object auotmatically.

Answer (score 19):

There's nothing wrong with if-then in functional world.

Your example is actually similar to `let _ = expr` since `expr` has side effects and we ignore its return value. A more interesting example is:

```
if cond then expr
```

which is equivalent to:

```
match cond with
| true -> expr
| false -> ()
```

if we use pattern matching.

When the condition is simple or there is only one conditional expression, if-then is more readable than pattern matching. Moreover, it is worth to note that everything in functional programming is expression. So `if cond then expr` is actually the shortcut of `if cond then expr else ()`.

If-then itself is not imperative, using if-then as a statement is an imperative way of thinking. From my experience, functional programming is more about the way of thinking than concrete control flows in programming languages.

**EDIT:**

Your code is totally readable. Some minor points are getting rid of redundant `do` keyword, type annotation and `postStream.Dispose()` (by using `use` keyword):

```
if not <| System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) then
    let byteData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)
    req.ContentLength <- int64 byteData.Length
    use postStream = req.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postStream.Flush()
```

Comment: In practice, `do` has its roles of signaling code fragments which have side effects and creating a new scope (important when going with `using` function).

Answer (score 12):

In order to write complex code, you need to branch at some point.  There's a very limited number of ways you can do that, and all of them require a logical flow through a section of code.  If you want to avoid using if/then/else it's possible to cheat with loop/while/repeat - but that will make your code far less reasonable to maintain and read.

Functional programming doesn't mean you shouldn't execute statements one after the other - it simply means that you shouldn't have a mutable state.  Each function needs to reliably behave the same way each time it is called.  Any differences in how data is handled by it need to be accounted for by the data that is passed in, instead of some trigger that is hidden from whatever is calling the function.

For example, if we have a function `foo(int, bool)` that returns something different depending on whether `bool` is true or false, there will almost certainly be an `if` statement somewhere in `foo()`.  That's perfectly legitimate.  What is NOT legitimate is to have a function `foo(int)` that returns something different depending on whether or not it is the first time it is called in the program.  That is a 'stateful' function and it makes life difficult for anyone maintaining the program.

Comment: I'm not sure that you answered the question but the original question is a little vague too. :-)

Answer (score 11):

It's not the if-expression that's imperative, it's what goes in the if-expression. For example, `let abs num = if num < 0 then -num else num` is a totally functional way to write the abs function. It takes an argument and returns a transformation of that argument with no side effects. But when you have "code that only does something, not return a value," *then* you're writing something that isn't purely functional. The goal of functional programming is to minimize the part of your program that can be described that way. How you write your conditionals is tangential.

Comment: Hey, I think I might've asked the wrong question. See my edit. It's more that I can't figure out the functional approach to minimizing and dealing with this sort of imperative code I guess.

Answer (score 9):

It's considered functional if your `if` statement has a return value and does not have side effects.

Suppose you wanted to write the equivalent of:

`if(x > 3) n = 3; else n = x;`

Instead of doing that, you use the return statement from the if command:

`let n = (if x > 3 then 3 else x)`

This hypothetical `if` is suddenly functional because it has no side effects; it only returns a value.  Think of it as if it were the **ternary operator** in some languages:  `int n = x>3?3:x;`

Comment: The `e ? e : e` operator is usually called **conditional operator**. A ternary operator is any operator that takes three arguments.

Comment: That's exactly why `a ? b : c` is called ternary.

Answer (score 3):

There are two observations that can assist in the transition from imperative to functional ("everything is an expression") programming:

1. `unit` is a value, whereas an expression returning `void` in C# is treated as a statement. That is, C# makes a distinction between statements and expressions. In F# *everything* is an expression.
2. In C# values can be ignored; in F# they cannot, therefore providing a higher level of type safety. This explicitness makes F# programs easier to reason about and provides greater guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for not knowing F#, but here is one possible solution in javascript:

```
function $if(param) {
    return new Condition(param)
}

function Condition(IF, THEN, ELSE) {
    this.call = function(seq) {
        if(this.lastCond != undefined) 
            return this.lastCond.call(
                sequence(
                    this.if, 
                    this.then, 
                    this.else, 
                    (this.elsif ? this.elsif.if : undefined),
                    seq || undefined
                )
            );
         else 
            return sequence(
                this.if, 
                this.then, 
                this.else, 
                (this.elsif ? this.elsif.if : undefined),
                seq || undefined
            )
    }


    this.if   = IF ? IF : f => { this.if = f; return this };
    this.then = THEN ? THEN : f => { this.then = f; return this };
    this.else = ELSE ? ELSE : f => { this.else = f; return this };
    this.elsif = f => {this.elsif = $if(f); this.elsif.lastCond = this; return this.elsif};
}

function sequence(IF, THEN, ELSE, ELSIF, FINALLY) {
    return function(val) {
        if( IF(val) ) 
            return THEN();

        else if( ELSIF && ELSIF(val) ) 
            return FINALLY(val);

        else if( ELSE ) 
            return ELSE();

        else 
            return undefined

    }
}}
```

The $if function returns an object with the if..then..else..elsif construct, using the Condition constructor.
Once you call Condition.elsif() you'll create another Condition object - essentially creating a linked list that can be traversed recursively using sequence()

You could use it like:

```
var eq = val => x => x == val ? true : false;

$if( eq(128) ).then( doStuff ).else( doStuff )
.elsif( eq(255) ).then( doStuff ).else( doStuff ).call();
```

However, I realize that using an object is not a purely functional approach. So, in that case you could forgo the object all together:

```
sequence(f, f, f, f,
    sequence(f, f, f, f
        sequence(f, f, f)
    )
);
```

You can see that the magic is really in the sequence() function. 
I won't try to answer your specific question in javascript. But I think the main point is that you should make a function that will run arbitrary functions under an if..then statement, then nest multiples of that function using recursion to create a complex logical chain. At least this way you will not have to repeat yourself ;)

This code is just a prototype so please take it as a proof of concept and let me know if you find any bugs.

Comment: I have to wonder... why? JavaScript already provides `b ? x : y`

Comment: I have yet to find a practical application for this. Mostly, it's just an exercise in functional programming. If it were practical to tear the entire  operating system apart, then you could implement this at the assembly level and allow every user space program to use predefined if-then statements (like a system-call) and you'd probably see a large memory savings... but that's not practical at all lol.

Comment: No. That is not how you do functional programming. 
This is on another level of crazy.