# C# to F#: Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have a syntax problem: I would like to put a condition in my controller. In C#, my condition is: `if (Request.Files["FileUpload"].ContentLength > 0)`

I can't succeed to translate in F#, any suggestions?

My code:

```
namespace FsWeb.Controllers

open System.Web.Mvc
open System
open System.Web 

[<HandleError>]

type HFAnalysisController() = 
    inherit Controller()

    member this.HFAnalysis () =
     this.View() :> ActionResult

    member this.Importexcel() = 
     // C# // if (Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength > 0)
```

Comment: And the problem is ... [if-then's syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233231.aspx), how to access a dictionary (it's `myDict.[key]`) or are you looking for a [more functional syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298419/whats-a-functional-replacement-for-if-then-statements)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am looking for a more functional syntax. I agree with you but F# doesn't like Request.Files[""].ContentLength. It seems that System.Web is different and HttpFileCollection doesn't have the same methods...

Comment: what do you mean `doesn't have the same methods`? It does have an indexer property. You will have to call `Request.Files.[]`

Comment: Peharps, it is due to a bad syntax, for example, if I try: let hfc : HttpFileCollection = Request.Files, I get The value of constructor Request is not defined

Comment: I suggest you provide all error info and the code you used, otherwise one can only guess what may be the problem. This time you raised a different issue, how to access the Request property

Comment: Being unclear helps no one and I simply apologize. Actually, your right, my problem is how to access the Request property

Comment: once you know your problem, you find easily the solution :-) Thank you Panagiotis for your help. Because I cannot inherit from System.Web.HttpApplication, we need to first create an object. Therefore the solution: let hfc = System.Web.HttpApplication()  
     let Request = hfc.Request or directly hfc.Request.Files.["FileUpLoad1"].ContentLength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the question is about how to get a dictionary value. In F# indexed properties [can't be called the same way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx) as in C#. The `Item[]` member has to be called explicitly:

```
this.Request.Files.["FileUpload1"].ContentLength
```

and you could write something like:

```
member this.ImportExcel() =
    if this.Request.Files.["FileUpload1"].ContentLength > 0 then
        ...
```